# How to run the sphinx?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

Yesterday I started to master the sphinx.

And everything was going well.

But today I can’t understand what my problem is.

When I create an index:

```
C:/sphinx/bin/indexer --all --config C:/sphinx/config/sphinx.conf
```

I connect the sphinx:

```
C:/sphinx/bin/searchd --install --config C:/sphinx/config/sphinx.conf --servicename SphinxSearch
```

I turn it on in services.

CMD command:

```
C:/Users/WINDOWS/Desktop/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9306
```

MySQL command:

```
show tables;
```

Conclusion:

```
Empty set (0.000 sec)
```

Config:

```
source src1
{
type = mysql

sql_host = localhost
sql_user = root
sql_pass =
sql_db = test
sql_port = 3306

sql_query = \
SELECT id, group_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP (date_added) AS date_added, title, content \
FROM documents

sql_attr_uint = group_id
sql_attr_timestamp = date_added
}


index test1
{
source = src1
path = C:/sphinx/data/test1
}


index testrt
{
type = rt
rt_mem_limit = 128M

path = C:/sphinx/data/testrt

rt_field = title
rt_field = content
rt_attr_uint = gid
}


indexer
{
mem_limit = 128M
}


searchd
{
listen = 9312
listen = 9306: mysql41
log = C:/sphinx/log/searchd.log
query_log = C:/sphinx/log/query.log
read_timeout = 5
max_children = 30
pid_file = C:/sphinx/log/searchd.pid
seamless_rotate = 1
preopen_indexes = 1
unlink_old = 1
workers = threads # for RT to work
binlog_path = C:/sphinx/data
}
```

Does not help:

```
C:/sphinx/bin/indexer --all --config C:/sphinx/config/sphinx.conf --rotate
```

PS.

Files are created in the C:/sphinx/data directory.

I deleted the service many times:

```
C:/sphinx/bin/searchd --servicename SphinxSearch --delete
```

And gave different names:

```
C:/sphinx/bin/searchd --install --config C:/sphinx/config/sphinx.conf --servicename RandomName
```

All my folders and files are in place.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.documents
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
group_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
group_id2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
date_added DATETIME NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
content TEXT NOT NULL
);

REPLACE INTO test.documents (id, group_id, group_id2, date_added, title, content) VALUES
(1, 1, 5, NOW (), 'test one', 'this is my test document number one. Also checking search within phrases.'),
(2, 1, 6, NOW (), 'test two', 'this is my test document number two'),
(3, 2, 7, NOW (), 'another doc', 'this is another group'),
(4, 2, 8, NOW (), 'doc number four', 'this is to test groups');

CREATE TABLE test.tags
(
docid INTEGER NOT NULL,
tagid INTEGER NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (docid, tagid)
);

INSERT INTO test.tags VALUES
(1,1), (1,3), (1,5), (1,7),
(2.6), (2.4), (2.2),
(3.15),
(4.7), (4.40);

SHOW DATABASES;

Empty set (0.002 sec)
```

Comment: What do indexer and searchd return when you run them?

Comment: The contents of C:/sphinx/log/searchd.log will be also helpful

Comment: I launched it by deleting the folder in 

`C:\Windows\system32\sphinxdata`

I also have two new problems, when indexing it writes:

`WARNING: word overrun buffer, clipped !!!`

and if I set in 
`sphinx.conf`

`blend_chars = +`

it will process the first 200k lines and crashes.

Comment: "word overrun buffer, clipped" means you have too long words. Check your charset_table configuration. As for the crash I can only recommend to try Manticore Search as lots of Sphinx bugs and crashes have been fixed there. Otrherwise file an issue in Sphinx' bugtracker - http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/